# AWS S3 - Get object results in 404 NoSuchKey

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK to put images into my S3 instance.  I am able to do this successfully via:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file));
```

I can also see the uploaded file if I browse the S3 system on the console page.  However, when I try to retrieve the same file via the SDK, I get a 404 "NoSuchKey" error:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

S3Object result = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
```

And here is the exact error:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;

Any one know why?

Comment: What is the key name you used in getObject() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your key name does not contain any of the special characters that will be URL decoded. One common scenario is if your key name contains '+' it will be decoded to empty space when you retrieve your key names using getKey() API of S3ObjectSummary class.

> ***Characters That Might Require Special Handling***
>
> The following
>   characters in a key name may require additional code handling and will
>   likely need to be URL encoded or referenced as HEX. Some of these are
>   non-printable characters and your browser might not handle them, which
>   also requires special handling:
>
> Ampersand ("&")
>
> Dollar ("$")
>
> ASCII character ranges 00–1F hex (0–31 decimal) and 7F (127 decimal)
>
> 'At' symbol ("@")
>
> Equals ("=")
>
> Semicolon (";")
>
> Colon (":")
>
> Plus ("+")
>
> Space – Significant sequences of spaces may be lost in some uses
>   (especially multiple spaces)
>
> Comma (",")
>
> Question mark ("?")

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Answer (score 4):

Same happened for me. Nothing was wrong in the file name and file existed in the correct folder under the bucket. The problem was that I had provided "/" just before the path that formed the key. Like if the folder structure was downloads/template under the bucket, I had specified the key as "/downloads/template". Got resolved by changing it to "downloads/template"